# Converting object to a different class

Tags: c++, class

Sandy is of class Person, who converts to Muslim and takes on a new name Fatima, and has all the attributes of Sandy, with new Muslim attributes (e.g. religion == Islam, etc..). At this point, Sandy can be deleted, and Fatima, now of class Muslim will play Sandy's role henceforth. The problem is that due to her new address, all the people who knew Sandy does not know Fatima. Manually changing Sandy's address to Fatima's address for all those people who knew Sandy is clearly not an acceptable method. Any suggestions on how to improve the design? Here's my simplified code showing the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

class Person {
        std::string name;
        Person* bestFriend;
    public:
        Person (const std::string& newName) : name (newName) {}
        virtual ~Person() = default;
        std::string getName() const {return name;}
        void setName (const std::string& newName) {name = newName;}
        Person* getBestFriend() const {return bestFriend;}
        void setBestFriend (Person* newBestFriend) {bestFriend = newBestFriend;}
};

class Muslim: public Person {
    public:
        Muslim (const Person& person) : Person (person) {
                          // religion = Islam; etc... 
                }
};

int main() {
    Person *mary = new Person ("Mary"), *sandy = new Person ("Sandy");
    mary->setBestFriend (sandy);
    std::cout << "sandy = " << sandy << ", " << typeid(*sandy).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << mary->getName() << "'s best friend is " << mary->getBestFriend()->
    getName() << "." << std::endl;
    Muslim* fatima = new Muslim (static_cast<Muslim>(*sandy));  // the big change
    fatima->setName ("Fatima");  // should now delete sandy, because fatima takes on every attribue of sandy
    std::cout << "fatima = " << fatima << ", " << typeid(*fatima).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << mary->getName() << "'s best friend is " << mary->getBestFriend()->
    getName() << "." << std::endl;  // still Sandy, of course
}
```

Output:

sandy = 0x32658, 6Person

Mary's best friend is Sandy.

fatima = 0x23fec0, 6Muslim

Mary's best friend is Sandy.

Of course, we want to have: Mary's best friend is Fatima, with mary->getBestFriend()->getReligion() == Islam, etc...
How to redesign the whole thing so that this is automated (assume there are thousands of people who know her)?

I want to use inheritance because class Muslim will have many complex overrides to Person methods (and many new data members and methods too).

Comment: Inheritance seems like overkill here. Why is there not just a `religion` member of `Person`?

Comment: @Joseph Mansfield. Because class Muslim will have many complex overrides to Person methods.

Comment: @prestokeys In that case, why not use dependency injection for these actions and inject a different set based on religion (assuming this is how your correlations work)

Comment: This is a well-known shortcoming of C++ that is not present in some other OO languages like Smalltalk. The workaround is, as always, adding a level of indirection. You have a Person class that represent the unchangeable (until the grim reaper comes) person, and PersonAttributes referenced by Person that you can transparently upgrade

Comment: "all the people who knew Sandy does not know Fatima".... likely the correct assumption if the behavior has been entirely replaced.  But your coding question is interesting nonetheless.

Comment: @n.m.: Yup, a form of pimpl.  Arguably, then, it's the implementation which is actually the `Person` object, and the wrapper is a `PersonLocator` or `PersonHandle` or something.

Comment: @BenVoigt well, the clients don't really need to know, they see a Person.

Comment: What about job, will you inherit Musician from Person as well? What special things are Muslims required to do that ordinary people aren't? (Also is a Person athiest??)

Answer (score 1):

My first approach would be, as @Joseph Mansfield suggested in the comments, to make `religion` an attribute of `Person`. Therefore, the change would only imply changes in the attributes and not a new Object.

Nevertheless, if to have a different class is mandatory for you, you could use the observer pattern. That is, any friend of a person should be subscribed (in a friend address book) list to the person changes. This subscriber have to implement a method from the same interface (subscriber) which should be called by the `Person` object when its attributes changes.

To sum up:

- Have a list of addresses to each friend at `Person` (`friends`).
- Each friend object class should implement a common interface where a change notification method is declared (`friendChanged(...)`)
- When `Person` changes by creating a new object of the new class, it has to traverse its `friends` list calling to `friendChanged` and passing them the new person object address. After that, you can destroy and deallocate the old object.

Finally, I don't think religion should be represented as a subclass. Religion sounds to me as a person feature and thus, it should be an attribute. There is a OOP principle which says: [Favor composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). You design seems to go artificially against that principle.

Comment: This looks like a good start. But suppose class BasketBallTeam has sandy as a member. So BasketBallTeam should have the same type of observer pattern subscription to take care of her change in address when Sandy turns into a new class? In essence very class that has pointer data members to Person should do likewise?  I don't mind implementing that (not much trouble at all), if that will make it all work.

Comment: @prestokeys You can make BasketBallTeam implement the observer interface (abstract class). You can even delegate BasketBallTeam observer implementation to each BasketBallTeam team member `friendChanged` method.

Comment: This is a fine solution, hovewer, one needs to be very accurate when implementing it in a multithreaded program, where simultaneous changes of mutual friends may occur.

Comment: @ nm.  Apart from that, can you predict any other exceptions that may occur with Pablo Hidalgo's method?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person;

class ObserverPersonInterface {
    public:
        virtual void registerObserver (Person*) = 0;
        virtual void removeObserver (Person*) = 0;
        virtual void notifyObservers() const = 0;       
};

class AddressChangeData : public ObserverPersonInterface {
    public:
        void addressChange (const Person* oldPerson, Person* newPerson) {
            oldAddress = oldPerson;
            newAddress = newPerson;
            // observers.remove (oldAddress);  // but not relevant here
            notifyObservers();
        }
        virtual void registerObserver(Person* person) override {
            observers.emplace_back (person);
        }
        virtual void removeObserver(Person* person) override {
            observers.remove (person);
        }
    private:
        virtual inline void notifyObservers() const override;

        std::list<Person*> observers;  // should perhaps be a red-black tree for greater efficiency
        const Person *oldAddress;
        Person *newAddress;
} changeOfAddressData;

class Person {
    public:
        Person() {
            changeOfAddressData.registerObserver(this);
        }
        // every new Person constructed is registered to changeOfAddressData
        Person(const std::string& newName) : name (newName) {
            changeOfAddressData.registerObserver (this);
        }
        virtual ~Person() = default;
        std::string getName() const {return name;}
        void setName (const std::string& newName) {name = newName;}
        Person* getBestFriend() const {return bestFriend;}
        void setBestFriend (Person* newBestFriend) {bestFriend = newBestFriend;}
    protected:
        void notifyChangeOfAddress(const Person* oldAddress, Person* newAddress) const {
            changeOfAddressData.addressChange (oldAddress, newAddress);
            delete oldAddress;
        }
    private:
        std::string name;
        Person* bestFriend;

};

class Muslim : public Person {
    public:
        Muslim() = default;
        Muslim(const Person& person) : Person(person) {
            changeOfAddressData.registerObserver (this);
            notifyChangeOfAddress (&person, this);
        }
};

inline void AddressChangeData::notifyObservers() const {
    for (Person* x : observers) {
        if(x->getBestFriend() == oldAddress) {
            x->setBestFriend(newAddress);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    Person *mary = new Person ("Mary"), *sandy = new Person ("Sandy");

    mary->setBestFriend (sandy);
    sandy->setBestFriend (mary);

    std::cout << "mary = " << mary << ", " << typeid(*mary).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sandy = " << sandy << ", " << typeid(*sandy).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << mary->getName() << "'s best friend is " << mary->getBestFriend()->getName() << "." << std::endl;
    std::cout << sandy->getName() << "'s best friend is " << sandy->getBestFriend()->getName() << "." << std::endl;

    Muslim* fatima = new Muslim(static_cast<Muslim>(*sandy));

    // all subscribers of changeOfAddressData notified of sandy's address change, sandy is deleted automatically
    fatima->setName("Fatima");

    std::cout << "fatima = " << fatima << ", " << typeid(*fatima).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << mary->getName() << "'s best friend is " << mary->getBestFriend()->getName() << "." << std::endl;
    std::cout << fatima->getName() << "'s best friend is " << fatima->getBestFriend()->getName() << "." << std::endl;

    Muslim* shazia = new Muslim (static_cast<Muslim>(*mary));
    // all subscribers of changeOfAddressData notified of mary's address change, mary is deleted automatically
    shazia->setName ("Shazia");

    std::cout << "shazia = " << shazia << ", " << typeid(*shazia).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << shazia->getName() << "'s best friend is " << shazia->getBestFriend()->getName() << "." << std::endl;
    std::cout << fatima->getName() << "'s best friend is " << fatima->getBestFriend()->getName() << "." << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: When writing code that you intend to post here, please set your IDE tab settings to 4 spaces and set replace tabs with spaces. This allows you to simply copy and paste the code as-is, highlight it, and then click the code block button and it will look as you typed it. Replacing tabs with spaces also prevents the code looking like an unintelligible mess if another person looking at your code has a different tab setting.

Comment: This is not an answer, it's just a whole of code. Please add context.

Comment: @ Jeffrey. If you run the code, it carries out the original task correctly.  The explanation was already given by Pablo Hidalgo, who suggested it.

Comment: Alas!  I discovered that the above code will not work if the class is a virtual derived class, because the old addresses will not be the same values.  What's the solution in that case?